# How do I show that $V_n$ is as required?

Tags: derivatives

**Question** : If $V_n=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^n \log x)$, show that $V_n=nV_{n-1}+(n-1)!$

Hence show that $$V_n=n! (\log x + 1 + \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dot{} \dot{} \dot{}+\frac{1}{n})$$

**What I have managed to do so far:**

I have found that $V_{n+1}=\frac{n!}{x}$ but I cannot use it further to answer the questions.

**PS**: Here $V_n$ is $n^{th}$ derivative of $V$

Can someone kindly guide me on how to pursue further in this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compute one of the derivatives in the definition of $V_n$ to get the recursion.

$$V_n = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} (x^n \log x) = \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} (n x^{n-1} \log x + x^{n-1}) = n V_{n-1} + (n-1)!$$

Then, applying this recursion repeatedly yields
\begin{align}
V_n
&= nV_{n-1} + (n-1)!\\
&= n[(n-1) V_{n-2} + (n-2)!] + (n-1)!
\\
&= n(n-1) V_{n-2} +  n! \left(\frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}\right)
\\
&\;\vdots\\
&= n! V_0 + n!\left(1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}\right),
\end{align}
where $V_0= \log x$.

Comment: So, basically. Answer was right in front of my eyes and I ignored it repeatedly :/